# Maven lifecycle and plugins

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

While reading about maven lifecycles and plugins , I have the following short doubts about maven , so posting in one thread :

1) Can we have our custom lifecycle in maven ?

2) Can we add custom phases to a pre existing life cycle in maven ?

3) Can a phase be associated to 2 or more goals at once ? If yes, how will maven decide the order of execution of the goals ?

4) Can a goal be associated to 2 or more phases ?

I am expecting short answers to each not any in depth explanation , however , if some body can provide that too , it will be awesome. I just don't want my question to be marked as too broad.

Comment: First question: Why do you need custom life cycles?

Comment: @khmarbaise , just for theoretical knowing. I was learning maven and these questions popped up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom lifecycles, but it is rarely useful. I have never done it. I would avoid it if possible.

You can add an arbitrary amount of goals to a phase. AFAIK, they are executed in the order they are given. You can also add a goal to different phases.

Comment: one question missed but answer is implicit : Can we add custom phases to a pre existing life cycle in maven ? I think answer would be yes ?

Comment: Simple answer is: No you can't

Comment: @JF Meier , when you said we can create a new lifecycle , can we have a custom phase (with a new name) or we can create a new lifecycle with only predefined phases ? I was reading this and question popped up : http://web.archive.org/web/20100308071320/http://www.sonatype.com:80/people/2009/08/create-a-customized-build-process-in-maven

Comment: I guess you could name them differently,  but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

1) not sure. Might be possible using extensions. But what purpose would that lifecycle have.

2) believe not. Again, if possible via externsions.

3) A phase is not associated with any goals.

Or rather executions are associated with a phase, if they are part of a lifecycle. If no phase is give within the execution, the default phase of the goal is used (which may be no phase!).

AFAIK, the order of executions within the same phase is determined by the order of the executions within the pom.

4) A goal is not really associated with a phase either. It only has a default phase. See 3.